# How to fill subreport in crystal report aspx with dataset

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have made two queries in dataset, then I want to set that query to the report
the first query is for the main report,
and the second query is for the subreport which have show by one of attribute field in main report.

Like I will show data (with where : from attribute field from main report)

Please anyone help me...

[image: this is the screenshot form the code]

^^ but this code is still wrong

Comment: paste your code instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
    ReportDocument RptDocument = new ReportDocument();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataSet ds = "Your Dataset";          
            CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Main Report";     
            RptDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("your rpt file path"));
            RptDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Table[0]);
            RptDocument.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RptDocument;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;           
    }
```

please refer this code

Comment: how if i use query from dataset? (tableadapter)

*) i use visual studio 2012

Comment: Then you have to take 2 different dataset and assign it to main report and sub report.